# How to represent this operator C# code into java?

Tags: c#, java, operators

What does the second line inside this for loop means and what will be the codes representation in java?

```
private List<int> channels = new List<int>();
private List<byte> packet= new List<int>();

      for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                channels.Add((int)packet[2 + (2 * i)]);
                channels[i] += ((int)packet[2 + (2 * i) + 1] << 8) & 0xFF00;
            }
```

Is this correct way to do above code in java?

```
            for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            channels.add(packet.get(2 + (2 * i)));

            byte temp=channels.get(i);
            temp+=((packet.get(2 + (2 * i) + 1) << 8) & 0xFF00);
            channels.set(i, temp);
        }
```

Above worked fine but, this would do things better. Thanks to every one for response:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          channels.set(i, (byte) (packet.get(2 + (2 * i))+((packet.get(2 + (2 * i) + 1) << 8) & 0xFF00)));
}
```

Comment: What part of that line is unclear to you?

Comment: 2nd line inside for loop after +=, what is << and & doing?

Comment: They are bit operations and work the same way in C# and [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Comment: "left shift" and "bitwise and" respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's missing from Java is operator overloading. As such, if you use an [`ArrayList<Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), you'll need to use [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) and
 [`set()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) instead of the `[]` operator.

Additionally, I don't think you could have assigned a `List<int>` to a `List<byte>` in C#.

Comment: It looks like it could work, but it would probably be more efficient to just add your sum to `channels` instead of adding the first term, retrieving it and adding to it.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is the bit left shift operator and `&` is bit-wise and.

It is the same in Java.

```
1 << 1 == 2
```

`0001` shifted to the left 1 is `0010`

```
1 & 0 == 0   // 01 & 00 == 00
1 & 1 == 1   // 01 & 01 == 01
1 & 2 == 0   // 01 & 10 == 00
1 & 3 == 1   // 01 & 11 == 01
```

Comment: what does it do? any example please?

Comment: `0001` shifted to the left 1 is `0010`

Comment: @DanielA.White: Do you know what `(variable << 8) & 0xFF00` does? Doesn't make sense to me using both operations.

Comment: @juergend - its doing a left bit shift 8 bits, then logical anding to the value `65280` which essentially is masking out the first byes.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense since the bit shift fills the variable with zeros.

Comment: @juergend - not necessarily. it will wrap around.

Comment: @Daniel, can you check the edited question? is it the correct way to so it?